# Arduino Nano HX711 Serial print issue

Tags: c, arduino

Friends, here is simple sketch doing only one thing, it is printing raw, not calibrated data from tension sensor.

```
#include <Q2HX711.h>
Q2HX711 hx711(A1, A0);
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    Serial.println(hx711.read());
}
```

Everything is ok, it prints the correct data with no drops or noises(tested for 6 hours). But if I add only one string to print before

```
Serial.print("0,");
Serial.println(hx711.read());
```

It begins print noisy data with big deviations, drops or splashes. There should be one more sensor(HMC588L) I removed it to test tension sensor, but this did not resolve the problem. Tension is very important I need noise-free data.

Hardware: [Arduino Nano](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardNano)

Library Q2HX711 installed from Arduino IDE library manager

Comment: I don't know anything about the Q2HX711 sensor, but from what you describe it sounds like you might be picking up noise from the serial port when you add the `Serial.print()` right before reading your sensor.  Maybe try adding a `delay(50)` in between (experiment with different values - longer or shorter)

Comment: I switched delay(20),delay(30),delay(40),delay(50) no result ( same "accidental" noise